# Password incorrect or New Password invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, change-password

Change password control is regularly failing my change attempt.

The control is very simple

```
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" Runat="server"
 BorderStyle="Solid" 
 BorderWidth="1" 
 CancelDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
 DisplayUserName="true" 
 ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" >
</asp:ChangePassword>
```

The error message is always the same

```
Password incorrect or New Password invalid. New Password length minimum: 4. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 0.
```

When my user logs in the Membership.ValidateUser I am getting a successful login.

```
 e.Authenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(userEmail, lgnLogin.Password);
 if (e.Authenticated)
 {
    //I am getting into this area for re-direct
 }
```

Can anyone clarify what might be causing this?

*************Edit 2/27/2015*********
Below is the web.config membership information.

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Default.aspx"  name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="MembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="AuthDBConnection" applicationName="Application" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="15" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
        <!--<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />-->
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: Have you tried ensuring that the password is correct or that the new password meets the minimum length of 4?  I don't think you've provided enough information for us to guess much else :P

Comment: Yes. The passwords are accurate and long enough. What other information do you need to research? It's obviously an open question where I'm looking for guidance.

Comment: Is the user already logged in when you're attempting to change the password?  are you using the default membership provider or an extended one?  Can you provide your web.config for the membership provider configuration?

Comment: I've added the membership information to my question. The user has logged in and has gone through the e.Authenticated area I listed above and were redirected to a new page upon e.Authentication==true. To me it looks like they are authenticated (because the redirect is hit)...